# not sure what exactly is wrong

Tags: python

I am new at python, probably as new as it gets. I am working on a simple python code for mpg and refactoring.  I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.  Its giving me a error on line 65, "in goodbye print("your miles per gallon:", mpg) name error name 'mpg' is not defined.  any help would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    miles_driven = 0.0
    gallons_of_gas_used = 0.0
    mpg = 0.0

    print_welcome()
    print_encouragement()
    goodbye()

    # imput
    miles_driven = your_miles_driven()
    gallons_of_gas_used = gas_used()


    # Calculation
    mpg = your_mpg(miles_driven, gallons_of_gas_used)

    print("Your miles per gallon:", mpg)

    print("\nThanks for using my mpg calculator, I will be adding additional "
      "functions soon!")

def print_welcome():
    print("Welcome to Ray's trip calculator!\n")

def print_encouragement():
    print("Let's figure out your miles per gallon!")

def your_miles_driven():
    your_miles_driven = 0.0
    your_miles_driven = float(input("Enter number of miles driven:"))
    return your_miles_driven

def gas_used():
    gas_used = 0.0
    gas_used = float(input("Enter the gallons of gas you used:"))
    return gas_used

def your_mpg(your_miles_driven, gas_used):
    mpg = 0.0
    your_mpg = your_miles_driven / gas_used
    return your_mpg

def goodbye():
    print("\nThanks for using my mpg calculator, I will be adding additional "
      "functions soon!")
    print("Your miles per gallon:" , mpg)

main()
```

Comment: Please choose a better, descriptive title for your question.

Comment: In `goodbye()`, `mpg` is not defined. In order to both debug your program and _help us to help you_ to debug your program, you are expected to create a [mre]. Had you done this here, you should have found that you could reduce the problem to only that function, and probably you would have found the solution yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. Try to think about the logic of your code and work through problems; don't just stop at the first error message. Error messages contain useful information; start by trying to **read and understand** them. "Any help would be appreciated" is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); this is **not a discussion forum**, help desk, tutorial center or debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 problems.

1. the `goodbye` function needs to receive `mpg` as an argument
2. you need to do the inputs before calling `goodbye()`, and pass the function the `mpg`

the following lines of code should be before calling `goodbye()`.

```
# input
miles_driven = your_miles_driven()
gallons_of_gas_used = gas_used()
```

Your code should look like this:

```
def main():
    print_welcome()
    print_encouragement()
    # input before goodbye()
    # input
    miles_driven = your_miles_driven()
    gallons_of_gas_used = gas_used()
    # after input calc the mpg
    # Calculation
    mpg = your_mpg(miles_driven, gallons_of_gas_used)
    # and then call the goodbye function and pass mpg
    goodbye(mpg)


def print_welcome():
    print("Welcome to Ray's trip calculator!\n")


def print_encouragement():
    print("Let's figure out your miles per gallon!")


def your_miles_driven():
    your_miles_driven = float(input("Enter number of miles driven:"))
    return your_miles_driven


def gas_used():
    gas_used = float(input("Enter the gallons of gas you used:"))
    return gas_used


def your_mpg(your_miles_driven, gas_used):
    your_mpg = your_miles_driven / gas_used
    return your_mpg


# goodbye function also needs to receive mpg
def goodbye(mpg):
    print("Your miles per gallon:", mpg)
    print("\nThanks for using my mpg calculator, I will be adding additional functions soon!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`mpg` is defined in your `main` function and is not passed to your `goodbye` function.  If you add it as a parameter, it becomes available in that function with whatever value is passed as an argument:

```
def goodbye(mpg):
    print("\nThanks for using my mpg calculator, I will be adding additional "
      "functions soon!")
    print("Your miles per gallon:" , mpg)
```

Now in your `main` function you can do:

```
    mpg = your_mpg(miles_driven, gallons_of_gas_used)
    goodbye(mpg)
```

and `goodbye()` will receive the value of `mpg` that was returned by `your_mpg()`.